# How do I turn an object I receive into another object with the data I want?

Tags: javascript, object

I get a JSON in the following format:

Where sellers are grouped by name and date showing the amount they sold on the day.

```js
{ 
   "Isabela Alves de Quadros":{ 
      "2019-10-22":4500,
      "2019-10-25":120,
      "2019-11-04":60
   },
   "Naiara":{ 
      "2019-10-25":5000,
      "2019-10-28":10,
      "2019-10-31":6000
   },
   "Nathália":{ 
      "2019-10-17":15,
      "2019-11-01":125
   }
}
```

I would like to turn it into an object as follows:

```js
{
 {
  name: "Isabela Alves de Quadros",
  data: [null, 4500, 120, null, null, null, 60]
 },
 {
  name: "Naiara",
  data: [null, null, 5000, 10, 6000, null, null]
 },
 {
  name: "Nathália",
  data: [15, null, null, null, null, 125, null]
 }
}
```

Where data that has no value, I put null.

Does anyone know how to do this or have an idea to show?

Already tried to make the map, but it did not work, searched in several places, but found nothing, maybe looking for some wrong way.

But thank you in advance who can help.

Comment: where data has no value? It seems like `null` is random to me, where is that derived from?

Comment: The value is null if you have no data. For example, on 10/17/2019 only one Nathália made a sale, the others not produced, for this null value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// Did it as a quick thing. Might not be an an efficient solution. 
// Run in http://playcode.io

```
const data = { 
   "Isabela Alves de Quadros":{ 
      "2019-10-22":4500,
      "2019-10-25":120,
      "2019-11-04":60
   },
   "Naiara":{ 
      "2019-10-25":5000,
      "2019-10-28":10,
      "2019-10-31":6000
   },
   "Nathália":{ 
      "2019-10-17":15,
      "2019-11-01":125
   }
}

console.log(data)
var names = Object.keys(data);
console.log(names);

var dates = Object.values(data);
console.log(dates);

var allDates =  dates.map((item) => (Object.keys(item)));
console.log(allDates);

var merged = ([].concat.apply([], allDates));
var dist = new Set(merged);
console.log(dist);

var finalData = [];

for(let name of names)
{ 
  var dates = [];
  for (let [key, value] of dist.entries())
  {
     var tempDates = data[name];
     if(tempDates[key] != undefined){
        dates.push(tempDates[key]);
      }
      else{
        dates.push(null);
      }
  }
  finalData.push( {name: name, data:dates})
} 

console.log(finalData);
```